# Custom preview in Fineuploader UI mode

Tags: fine-uploader

I'm evaluating fineuploader for my company, so far it has fulfilled all but one of our requirements that I still haven't figured out. I'm working with the Jquery wrapper and UI mode (with autoUpload = false) and trying to display a custom preview depending on the file extension of the file for non-image files (e.g. PDFs, Word, Excel, etc.) so if the user selects an image they will see a preview but if they select a Word document they will see the appropriate icon. I know there's the thumbnail.placeholders option but that will display the same image when a preview is not possible and not a different one based on the file extension, is there any way to achieve this in UI mode?

Answer (score 1):

Only one placeholder image may be specified at the moment.  If you'd like something a bit more complex, you will need to [open up a feature request in the Github project's issue tracker](https://github.com/FineUploader/fine-uploader/issues/new).